# Text placement after overlay TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, titles

Suppose I want to customize a title with TikZ using relative placement to the node `current page`. I would typically do something as:

```
\documentclass[10pt,english,a4paper]{article} %

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My very fancy cute title, that I make long for expository
  purpose}%
\author{John Doe}%
\date{Today}%
%

\makeatletter

\pgfmathsetmacro\barshift{\marginparwidth}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\frombar{\marginparsep}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\topshift{1in+\voffset+\topmargin}%

\def\@bgcolor{blue!70!green!90!red!90!white}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    % title placement
    \coordinate (top-bar) at ([xshift=\barshift,yshift=-\topshift]
    current page.north west);%
    \node [anchor=north west,xshift=\frombar] (title) at (top-bar) {%
      \begin{minipage}{.7\linewidth} %
        \Huge \color{black} \sffamily \@title %
      \end{minipage} %
    };%
    \coordinate (bottom-bar) at ([xshift=-\frombar] title.south west); 
    \draw [\@bgcolor,line width=.5em] (top-bar) -- (bottom-bar);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle
% \vskip 5em
\lipsum % HERE, without the \vskip, the beginning is printed on top of the title !

\end{document}
```

But now, if I write some text in the document (`\lipsum` in the MWE), the `overlay` option (needed to reference to `current page`) prints it **on top** of my fancy title. Something that I obviously don't want...

For a one time title customization, it is ok as I can add something as `\vskip 5em` and adjust the spacing *by hand* just before typing my text. But if I'm coding a package, I need to find this spacing automatically. There I'm stuck... How can I detect the end of an `overlay` TikZ picture?

Comment: Please make your code complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but I think it is necessary to better understand your problem and help you.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Done. Hope it helps to understand the problem better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to not use `overlay` at all, and calculate the title's position relative to the top corner of the text (its default position) instead of relative to the page:

```
\documentclass[10pt,english,a4paper]{article} %

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My very fancy cute title, that I make long for expository purpose}%
\author{John Doe}%
\date{Today}%
%

\makeatletter

\def\@bgcolor{blue!70!green!90!red!90!white}

\pgfmathsetmacro\barshift{1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin-\marginparwidth}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\frombar{\marginparsep}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\topshift{\headheight+\headsep}%
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % title placement
    \coordinate (top-bar) at (-\barshift pt,\topshift pt);%
    \node [anchor=north west, inner xsep=\frombar] (title) at (top-bar) {%
      \begin{minipage}{.7\linewidth} %
        \Huge \color{black} \sffamily \@title %
      \end{minipage} %
    };%
    \coordinate (bottom-bar) at (title.south west);
    \draw [\@bgcolor,line width=.5em] (top-bar) -- (bottom-bar);
    \pgfresetboundingbox
    \path[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (title.south east);
  \end{tikzpicture}

}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: If you must use overlay, you can extract and globally store the y coordinate of the bottom of the title, which will of course be in the (offset) page coordinates:

```
\documentclass[10pt,english,a4paper]{article} %

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My very fancy cute title, that I make long for expository
  purpose}%
\author{John Doe}%
\date{Today}%
%

\makeatletter

\pgfmathsetmacro\barshift{\marginparwidth}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\frombar{\marginparsep}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\topshift{1in+\voffset+\topmargin}%

\def\@bgcolor{blue!70!green!90!red!90!white}

\newdimen\titlebottom
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    % title placement
    \coordinate (top-bar) at ([xshift=\barshift,yshift=-\topshift]
    current page.north west);%
    \node [anchor=north west,xshift=\frombar] (title) at (top-bar) {%
      \begin{minipage}{.7\linewidth} %
        \Huge \color{black} \sffamily \@title %
      \end{minipage} %
    };%
    \coordinate (bottom-bar) at ([xshift=-\frombar] title.south west);
    \draw [\@bgcolor,line width=.5em] (top-bar) -- (bottom-bar);
    \pgfextracty{\global\titlebottom}{\pgfpointanchor{title}{south}}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{-1\titlebottom}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what if I really need the relative positioning to `current page`? TikZ & pgf manual is so heavy, I don't know where to search for that inside it. (Of course, my example here does not match my exact need, it is just for the sake of simplicity.)

Comment: @Pece Okay, I've added another solution which uses overlay.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the suggestion. I've changed it.

Comment: Tanks, the extraction is exactly what I needed !